# rearrangements of ONTOLOGY without adjacent Os

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many different ways i can rearrange (in a row) the letters in the word **ONTOLOGY**, so that O doesn't show up twice in a row.

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: i thought about 6!

Comment: More detail, and [edit your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2070847/edit) to add it.

Comment: Do you mean all the 'O's must be separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that restriction is 'no two 'o's can come together' Then answer is $2400$.

See the output from [this tool](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/word/index.php)

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should've attempted the question yourself and showed us where you've gotten otherwise you won't get help. This isn't a homework website.

Regardless,
What are the total ways of arranging it?

8!/3!

The 3! is to account for the repetition of the 3 O's.

Then you calculate the number of ways O's CAN show up twice in a row.

Group the 2 O's as one entity and permute all entities. Because the 3 O's are in one group, there are now only 7 groups.

So 7!

Answer: Total ways of arranging ONTOLOGY - number of ways O's CAN show up twice in a row = 6720 - 5040 = 1680

Next time, show what you've done yourself.

Comment: i think no two 'o's can come together is the question. $6000$ is the number of arrangements where all the 'O's do not appear together.